# Qlik Sense Scheduler Stopped after removing and adding back proxy node

Tags: qliksense

need some advice.

After we removed the proxy node and added it back. The scheduler service stopped and is stuck at "Starting".
Seeking all for any advice to make it start..

The event log shows error:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the scheduler service and any other services that it depends on like repository service.